# Sharing the Pi's WiFi connection through the Ethernet port using network manager

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ethernet, networkmanager

https://youtu.be/8qzHwqFBFh4

I followed this link to share my mobile hotspot to my windows desktop using raspberry pi 3 with network manager. Once the setup is complete, I noticed a poor internet connection in comparative when using a usb tethered internet from my mobile... Can anyone help me understand why and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Avoid adding a video link. Please add all the procedure you have done and what was your problem then what you did to fix it.

Comment: What speeds are you getting? I need to see a comparison. Also, monitor how hard the Pi is working -- is CPU or RAM usage really high?

Comment: @user96931 I am having 4g connection.... i didn't notice cpu usage since i was not running application even in the background... but usb tethered internet connection was speedy.. where as here it was not even loading google homepage quickly.... it was dead slow

Comment: sure @M. Rostami